# addHTML is downloading empty pdf,not showing content of div

Tags: html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I have used jspdf and htmltocanvas to convert dom object into PDF, but addHTML is downloading empty pdf.

addHTML return promise, but not showing content in PDF.

Comment: addHTML was never really implemented. And was declared officially unsupported from v 1.4